Discrapencies in session spring
I've notcied some discrepancies while testing Spring authentication and wondering why it has happened.
I've noticed discrepancies between JSESSION Cookie in a browser and sessionID I can see in server logs.
Every time I authenticate, JSESSION Cookie is different than session on the server.
Why is that? Is it expected behavior? I suppose they should be the same every time?


My configuration file:
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().and().cors().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin();
        return http.build();

    }
}

Best,

Yes,it's expected behavior.
ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy is an authentication strategy in Spring Security. Its function is to update or replace the current session ID to protect against session fixation attacks after the user is successfully authenticated.
